# On category of matroids

Tags: category-theory, matroids

In the paper

https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/cheunen/publications/2015/matroids/matroids.pdf

the category of matroids and strong maps is defined and investigated. In Section 8, the authors take into account various matroidal constructions, following some relevant constructions by Brylawksi. Among these, the authors analyze free extensions (see Definition 8.5). In the successive remark, they show that free extensions are not functorial. Let us see the example: the ground set of the matroid $M$ is the $2$-set $\{a,b\}$ while that of the matroid $N$ is the $4$-set $\{a,b,c,d\}$. When freely extending $M$, the authors should use $p$ instead of $d$. Something on the flats of $X(N)$ should be corrected. In fact, we must have

$$
\mathcal{F}_{X(N)}=\{\emptyset,a,b,c,d,p,ab,ac,ad,bc,bd,cd,ap,bp,cp,dp,abp,acp,adp,bcp,bdp,cdp,abcdp\}
$$

instead of the family given by the authors. However, it is true that there is no strong map from $X(M)$ to $X(N)$ whose restriction to $M$ and $N$ agrees with $f$. The problem is the next sentence: "Hence X(f) cannot be canonically defined in a way that respects identities, and the free extension cannot be functorial". What do the authors exactly mean?

Comment: I think Kevin Arlin's answer is what you are looking for so I deleted my answer to turn it into a comment: when the authors say "the free extension
cannot be functorial", actually it is false, technically. You can always send every morphism to the constant to $p$. I don't see other possible functorialities, but one could try to classify them based on a hypothesis that the functoriality should "respect the isomorphisms" in some way (too long for a comment). (You even have a natural transformation from the identity: everything to the constant to $p$; but it's not the inclusion one would like.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The “that agree with $f$” part of the note shows that this extension construction cannot be made functorial in a manner allowing a natural transformation from the identity functor, something you would naturally want out of an extension operation.